# How to populate Angular controller variables from an array that is retrieved by $http.get

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-controller

Using Angular 1.5.9 on frontend and WebAPI 2 on server. Calling a standard `$http.get` in the service to `Get()` method on controller. This is returning the ViewModel that I want to populate variables with in angular controller.

```
var carListController = function ($http, $scope, carService) {

    var model = this;

    model.carList = carService.getCarsByMake('Bentley', 10);

    console.log(model.carList);

    model.cars = model.carList[0].cars;

    model.totalCars = model.carList[0].totalCars;

    model.numberOfPages = model.carList[0].numberOfPages;

};
```

I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'cars' of undefined

[image: Error Message]

As you can see the `console.log` is showing the `model.carList` so I know issue is in controller code populating the other variables. What am I missing here? Any help appeciated.

**Edit:** carService

```
var cars = [];

var carService = function ($http) {

    var getCarsByMake = function (make, size) {

        $http.get('http://localhost:50604/api/cars?make=' + make + '&size=' + size)
            .then(function (response) {
                // Success
                angular.copy(response.data, cars);
            }, function () {
                // Failure
            });

        return cars;
    };

    return {
        getCarsByMake: getCarsByMake
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your `$scope` variable population in a promise approach.
Since the `model.carList` data is not yet loaded when the population is happening, it's normal that the error arrises (Cannot read property 'cars' of undefined; meaning carList is undefined).

In your service `carService.getCarsByMake` you have to return a `promise`(  `$http.get` method)

Only when the promise is resolved, you can populate your `$scope`variables with this data.

```
var carListController = function ($http, $scope, carService) {    
    var model = this;    
    carService.getCarsByMake('Bentley', 10).then(function(response){
        model.carList = response.data;
        model.cars = model.carList.cars;
        model.totalCars = model.carList.totalCars;
        model.numberOfPages = model.carList.numberOfPages;
    });    

};
```

Return `$http` request on the service side :

```
var cars = [];
var carService = function ($http) {
    var getCarsByMake = function (make, size) {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:50604/api/cars?make=' + make + '&size=' + size);
    };

    return {
        getCarsByMake: getCarsByMake
    };
};
```

Comment: I did try that but getting error - `TypeError: carService.getCarsByMake(...).then is not a function` - I am just returing an array from service - is that correct approach?

Comment: Can you also share you `carService.getCarsByMake` function?

Comment: Added above - so need to return promise from the carService but not sure how?

Comment: See the edited answer above . Just return the `$http` angularjs object, which is in fact also a promise. On the controller side use the `response.data` object value on the `then` handler.

Comment: Was still getting the same error - swapped variales to e.g. `model.cars = response.data.cars;` and boom its all working. Thanks for the help. Kicking myself because I tried all this before asked the question. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Great to hear :) Although the `model.carList = response.data;  model.cars = model.carList.cars;` should also work.